# Limit of $\lim_{x\to0}\,\ln(x-\ln(x))$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you find the following limit: $$\lim_{x\to0}\,\ln(x-\ln(x))$$ It's a necessary step to solve a Putnam problem I'm working on, and I think once it's evaluated the problem is solved; however I'm unable to do so.

Comment: What's the problem with this limit?

Comment: 2016 B-1 the way I'm solving it the sum of the series is equal to $e^{x_{n+1}}-1$ So you evaluate the $lim_{x\to\infty}x_{n+1}$ which is sort of equivalent to the limit above.

Comment: I think you're talking about things that only you are aware of. Look at the hint by Robert Israel

Comment: Apologies I read your comment as “which one is the problem with this limit?” My misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem. I guess you were talking of a certain exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $1>x>0;$

$\log (x-\log x) >$

$ \log (-\log x) \rightarrow  +\infty$ for $x \rightarrow 0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: as $x \to 0+$, $\ln(x) \to -\infty$, so $x - \ln(x) \to \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

to make asense ,take $x=e^{-t},t \to \infty$ so 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\,\ln(x-\ln(x))\\
=\lim_{t \to \infty}\,\ln(e^{-t}-\ln(e^{-t}))\\
=\lim_{t \to \infty}\,\ln(e^{-t}+t)\\
$$
and $e^{-t}$ tends to zero
so $$=\lim_{t \to \infty}\,\ln(e^{-t}+t)=\ln(0+\infty)\to +\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$x-\ln x\to\infty\implies\ln(x-\ln x)\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}x=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}\ln x=-\infty$.

So $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}(x-\ln x)=+\infty$.

This implies that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}\ln(x-\ln x)=+\infty$. (The condition must be changed to $x\rightarrow0^+$, otherwise the function $\ln(x-\ln x)$ may not be defined.)

Comment: That has already been said in the answer by Robert Israel. The function will definitely be undefined because $\log$ isn't defined for negative inputs.